# Как сделать несколько COUNT в одном запросе?

Tags: sql

СУБД: MySQL 8.0.29

Есть таблица:

```
CREATE TABLE orders ( id INT, userId INT, tripType varchar(255) );
INSERT INTO `orders` (`id`, `userId`, `tripType`) VALUES
(1, 1, 'way'), (2, 2, 'way'), (3, 3, 'way'),
(4, 1, 'on-road'), (5, 2, 'on-road'), (6, 3, 'way');
SELECT * FROM orders;
```

Как посчитать сколько пользователь выполнил заказов всего и сколько по типам, в одной выборке?

Например, чтобы узнать, сколько всего, я делаю группировку по пользователю:

```
SELECT userId, COUNT(*) totalOrders FROM orders GROUP BY 1
```

Чтобы узнать, сколько по типам:

```
SELECT userId, tripType, COUNT(*) totalOrderByTripType FROM orders GROUP BY 1, 2
```

Хочу увидеть сумму по странам и сумму по типам:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[Пример.](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=58a26ecebf21dc76db95d66879c0f588)

Comment: SELECT A.userId, B.tripType, B.totalOrderByTripType, A.totalOrders
FROM (SELECT userId, COUNT(*) totalOrders FROM orders GROUP BY userId) A INNER JOIN 
     (SELECT userId, tripType, COUNT(*) totalOrderByTripType FROM orders GROUP BY userId, tripType) B
     ON A.userId = B.userId
ORDER BY  B.tripType, A.userId

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Используйте [WITH ROLLUP](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-modifiers.html) чтоб сделать свертки существующих групп и `HAVING GROUPING(...)` чтоб отсеять ненужные свертки:

```
SELECT userId, tripType, COUNT(*) totalOrderByTripType
FROM orders 
GROUP BY 1, 2 
WITH ROLLUP
HAVING GROUPING(userId) = 0
```